# Bash - does 'more' command block writing on file?

Tags: file-locking

If I execute the command 'more' on a file while a program is writing on that file, does the program stop or halt or can't write anymore?

Comment: It should not be affected, but this question is off-topic: nothing related to coding.

Comment: Thanks. Anyway I think it's surely related with tags I used. @Poshi

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your advice. Sorry but I'm new here!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`more` reads the file and some other program writes the file. This can happen simultaneously as long as no [mandatory file locking](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/mandatory-locking.txt) is used. So opening a file with more has no impact on other programs writing the file.